# How to deal with temporary pointer in precise garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection

Register may contain value of a pointer. When calling a function, that value is saved automatically, so there's more pointer values in the stack apart from params and locals. How to deal with that in a precise garbage collection using stack map?

Comment: Your stack map needs to include all the pointers that are saved on the stack in this way.  This info may be spread between caller and callee (caller puts a pointer into a callee-saved reg and callee saves that reg on the stack), so representing it is more complex than just stack frames with params and locals.

Comment: You have to deal with pointers on the stack anyway, e.g. when evaluating `foo(pointer, new bar())` and the allocation of `bar` requires garbage collection while `pointer` is on the stack. (You can map operand stack elements to registers but since there’s only a small number of registers, you can always raise the number of intermediate values to a scenario where values have to be on the stack)